# finding two pairs from integer array out of two elements

Tags: java, algorithm

Two pairs: If there are two pairs of dice with the same number, the player scores the sum of these dice. If not, the player scores 0. For example, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3 placed on "two pairs" gives 8.

examples:
1,1,2,3,3 results 8
1,1,2,3,4 results 0
1,1,2,2,2 results 6

How can find this efficiently?

I've been using following code to find a single pair

```
int max_difference = 0;
int val1 = 0 , val2 = 0;
Arrays.sort(dice);
for (int i = 0; i < dice.length - 1; i++) {
    int x = dice[i+1] - dice[i];
    if(x <= max_difference) {
        max_difference = x;
        val1 = dice[i];
        val2 = dice[i+1];

    }
}
pairScore = val1 + val2;
```

Comment: "two pairs" = 2 x 2 dice with the same value? So if I have 1, 1, 2, 3, 4 the result is 0? What about 1, 1, 1, 2, 2? And 1, 1, 1, 1, 2?

Comment: @Mark it should result sum of both that means 6(1+1+2+2)

Comment: In which case should it be 6? 1, 1, 1, 2, 2? So it doesn#t matter that there are 3 1s it still counts as a pair?

Comment: @Jonny where does it say he's rolling four dice?

Comment: @JonnyHenly user is rolling five dice

Comment: @JonnyHenly thats why their are 5 numbers in the array

Comment: @Jonny Henly yes, because those 5 dice results contained two pairs (1 and 3) ;)

Comment: @Mark Oh I thought OP was saying that rolling two pairs of dice resulted in 5 numbers :D, I see where I went wrong.

Comment: The distinct values are limited. So use bucket sorting, or frequency map as @Thomas answered.

Comment: Just a side note: if I'm not mistaken your code wouldn't detect if there is no pair, i.e. if you have values 1,2,3,4,5 the lowest value for `x` and `max_difference` (that name is misleading btw) would be 1 and you'd get a pair score of 9 (4 + 5).

Comment: Thanks @Thomas i didnt notice ill fix it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a frequency map, i.e. the number is the key and the value is a counter (so a `Map<Integer, Integer>`). However, since it is used for dices you could simplify that using an array with a length equal to the maximum dice value (6 for standard dice). Then check the frequencies for each number and get the number of pairs from it.

Example:

```
int[] diceFrequency = new int[6];

//assuming d is in the range [1,6]
for( int d : dice ) {
  //increment the counter for the dice value
  diceFrequency[d-1]++; 
}

int numberOfPairs = 0;
int pairSum = 0;

for( int i = 0; i < diceFrequency.length; i++ ) {
  //due to integer division you get only the number of pairs, 
  //i.e. if you have 3x 1 you get 1 pair, for 5x 1 you get 2 pairs
  int num = diceFrequency[i] / 2;

  //total the number of pairs is just increases
  numberOfPairs += num; 

  //the total value of those pairs is the dice value (i+1) 
  //multiplied by the number of pairs and 2 (since it's a pair)
  pairSum += (i + 1 ) * 2 * num;
}

if( numerOfPairs >= 2 ) {
  //you have at least 2 pairs, do whatever is appropriate
}
```

Comment: hey diceFrequency[d-1]++; what does this do?

Comment: diceFrequency[d-1]++; what does this do?

Comment: `//increment the counter for the dice value`. It's written in comments

Comment: `diceFrequency[d-1]++` increases the value of the element at index `d-1` by 1. Since the array index is 0-based but the dice value is 1-based you need to use `d-1` instead of just `d`.

Comment: @RamanSahasi to be fair I added the comments after the question since I realized some more explanation is needed.

Answer (score 5):

No need to make it that complicated, since you're only searching for the resulting number...

```
int prev = 0;
int result = 0;
int pairs = 0;

Arrays.sort(dice);
for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) 
{
    int current = dice[i];
    if (current == prev) 
    {
        result += current*2;
        pairs++;
        prev = 0;
    } 
    else prev = current;
}

if (pairs == 2) return result;
else return 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

How about use hashmap as below?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = Lists.newArrayList(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4);
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = Maps.newHashMap();

    int result = 0;

    for (int i : list) {
        int frequency = (int) MapUtils.getObject(map, i, 0);

        if (frequency < 2) {
            map.put(i, ++frequency);
        }
    }

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() > 1) {
            result += entry.getKey() * entry.getValue();
        }
    }

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: AFAIK that kind of map is called a frequency map (just for future reference :) ). Besides that you could optimize the second loop by using `entrySet()` since you'd then not have to do additional lookups.

Comment: The keySet() is replaced by the entrySet() as @Thomas said. Thanks for advice.

Comment: When you have a full house (e.g. 2 2 2 3 3), your code counts all the dice, it probably should only count two of the 2s.

Comment: @Roland Illig You have a good point. It was fixed as above. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = Lists.newArrayList(1, 1, 2, 3, 3);
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    int count= 0;

    for (int num : list)
        if(map.containsKey(num ))
            map.put(num , map.get(num )+1);
        else
            map.put(num , 1);

    for (int num  : map.keySet()) {
        if (map.get(num ) > 1) {
            count= count+ (num  * map.get(num ));
        }
    }

    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope, I could understand the problem. So we can use thiscode part.

```
    List<Integer> diceList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    diceList.add(1);
    diceList.add(1);
    diceList.add(2);
    diceList.add(4);
    diceList.add(3);
    diceList.add(3);
    diceList.add(6);
    diceList.add(8);

    Integer prev = null, score = 0;

    boolean flag = false;
    for (Integer val : diceList) {
        if (prev == null || !prev.equals(val)) {
            if (flag) {
                score = score + prev;
                flag = false;
            }
            prev = val;

        } else if (prev == val) {
            score = score + prev;
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(score);
```